# Postgres Jsonb datatype

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I am using PostgreSQL to create a table based on json input given to my Java code, and I need validations on JSON keys that is passed on the database just like oracle but problem here is the whole jsonb datatype column name lets say **data** is single column. Consider I get json in below format -

```
{
  "CountActual": 1234,
  "CountActualCharacters": "thisreallyworks!"
  "Date": 09-11-2001
}
```

Correct datatype of above json:- `number(10)`, `varchar(50)`, `date`

Now to put validations on I'm using constraints

***Query 1 -***

```
ALTER TABLE public."Detail"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "CountActual" 
    CHECK ((data ->> 'CountActual')::bigint >=0 AND length(data ->> 'CountActual') <= 10);
```

--Working fine.

But for ***Query 2***-

```
ALTER TABLE public."Detail"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "CountActualCharacters" 
    CHECK ((data ->> 'CountActualCharacters')::varchar >=0 AND length(data ->> 'CountActualCharacters') <= 50);
```

I'm getting below error -

```
[ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying >= integer
HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). 
You might need to add explicit type casts.]
```

I tried another way also like -

```
ALTER TABLE public."Detail"
    ADD CONSTRAINT CountActualCharacters CHECK (length(data ->> 'CountActualCharacters'::VARCHAR)<=50)
```

Above constraints works successfully but I don't think this is the right way as my validation is not working when inserting the data -

```
Insert into public."Detail" values ('{" 
  CountActual":1234,
  "CountActualCharacters":789
  "Date": 11-11-2009
}');
```

And its shows insert successfully when passing in 789 in CountActualCharacters instead of varchar like "the78isgood!".

So please can anyone suggest me proper constraint for PostgreSQL for `varchar` just like `number` that I have written  in Query 1.

And if possible for Date type also with `DD-MM-YYYY` format.

I just started with PostgresSQL, forgive me if I'm sounded silly but I'm really stuck here.

Comment: What do you mean with "Just like Oracle"? Oracle can only validate if the JSON is structurally valid, nothing more.

Comment: Sounds like a case of [unnecessary JSON](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/). If you really need data _type_ validation, then use regular columns with the correct data type.

Comment: that was my bad. Right now, I need to validate the contents of input json.

Comment: The whole json data is in single column buddy....

Comment: Your check constraint validates that not more than 50 characters can be stored for the key `CountActualCharacters` just like a `varchar(50)` would do. Why do you expect it to fail when storing 3 characters like `789`?

Comment: I know it's a single column - but it's violating proper normalization rules for relational database.

Comment: it should fail because 789 is like number(integer) but the validation should work on  varchar, it should validate the data in "gfdufu" this format not integer format.

Comment: But that's not the validation a `varchar(50)` would do and `'789'` is a perfectly valid string as well

Answer (score 2):

You can use `jsonb_typeof(data -> 'CountActualCharacters') = 'string'`

Note the single arrow, as `->>` will try to convert anything to string.

You can read more about JSON functions in PostgreSQL here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

Comment: Thanks alexey, but in that article there is no mention of varchar,  and if i use string then blankspaces and whitespaces are also included in json will passed the validation. I need this "thu45io89" to validate not "ths   097 ndkn lp". :)

Comment: You're confusing JSON types with DB types. They are different. And not accepting spaces is your business logic, not something a type would validate.

Comment: @Ankur: you should edit your question and add the check constraint that you currently use in Oracle